# What structure X509Certificate2.Handle points to in Linux?

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate, .net-5

I know, that for Windows `X509Certificate2` uses Crypt32, and [`X509Certificate2.Handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.handle?view=net-5.0) points to [`CERT_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-cert_context) structure.

On the other hand in Linux `X509Certificate2` uses Open SSL under the hood. So, what structure `X509Certificate2.Handle` points to in this case?

Is it the same `CERT_CONTEXT` or something else?

Comment: See here, which is what the Unix PAL for x509 handle calls into for creation (and the comments above it) https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/Interop.X509Stack.cs,36

Comment: I know that doesn't give you direct answer, but you may be able to use the information in the comment and the entry point the extern method refers to for your answer. It's distinctly different from the windows version, but that's the most I can say

Comment: `CERT_CONTEXT` on the other hand is part of the windows source (however there are no direct references to it)... Its part of `Interop.WinCrypt` so I think perhaps it's not used in Linux (but cannot say for absolute certainty) https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.DotNet.SignCheckLibrary/Interop/WinCrypt.cs,ac906376dd255703,references

Comment: Here are the links to how I found the one in my first comment. This call to `CertificatePal.FromHandle` gets passed the handle that is created by the call in the 1st link: https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/Internal/Cryptography/Pal.Unix/PkcsFormatReader.cs,246 And here's the Unix PAL itself https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/Internal/Cryptography/Pal.Unix/CertificatePal.cs - - called by https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/Internal/Cryptography/Pal.Unix/OpenSslX509CertificateReader.cs,29

Comment: And finally, you can see the entire Unix PAL layer from any of those last three links by looking at the expanded folder in the navigation (Internal/Cryptogtaphy/PAL.Unix) where you'll find almost the entire Linux implementation for certificates. It might provide further information that can lead you to what you seek.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, thanks. I looked into the sources, but stucked on native APi call to Open SSL with no idea where to go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an OpenSSL `X509*` value.

On all platforms it represents "a pointer that the system cryptographic library produced that represents an X.509 public key certificate".  So Windows it's a `PCERT_CONTEXT`, macOS it's a `SecCertificateRef`, and Linux it's an `X509*`.

On all platforms, you really should have a very good reason before you use the Handle value.

Comment: Well, I have a reason to work with handles. .NET doesn't support Russian national cryptographic standards and still cannot be extended to use third party provider due to ugly architecture inside. Actually, you know this. ) That's why I have to deal with native library, which mimics Windows Crypto API on Linux. There's no another way to get cross-platform cryptography in my case. Just wanted to ensure, that memory representation differs depending on platform. Thanks a lot!